# Merge two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have something like this:

```
Dict1 = {'a': "blabla", 'b': "gugu"}
Dict2 = {'a': "tadaa", 'b': "duduu"}
```

what I want to have is:

```
Dict3 = {'tadaa': "blabla", 'duduu': "gugu"}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: oh.. common.. already got great help. My code is way more complicate (so is my tried solution). So this way was the easiest way to ask - and I got great help. and.. as it was my very first question I dindnt got how to implement the example as code, but @jonrsharpe helped out in a great way and I know now :) thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over one dictionary's keys and values, use the value as key in a new dictionary and use the key to pull the associated value out of the second dictionary. In [a single expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> Dict1 = {'a': "blabla", 'b': "gugu"}
>>> Dict2 = {'a': "tadaa", 'b': "duduu"}    
>>> {v: Dict1[k] for k, v in Dict2.items()}
{'duduu': 'gugu', 'tadaa': 'blabla'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, this depends on what the edge cases are, and what you want to do about them (for example, what if the keys in `Dict1` and `Dict2` can be different?

Here's a solution that discards keys which only occur in one of the two dicts:

```
>>> Dict1 = {'a': "blabla", 'b': "gugu", 'x': 'nope'}
>>> Dict2 = {'a': "tadaa", 'b': "duduu", 'y': 'nuh-uh'}

>>> {Dict2[k]: Dict1[k] for k in set(Dict1) & set(Dict2)}
{'tadaa': 'blabla', 'duduu': 'gugu'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Would something like this work?

```
Dict3 = dict(zip(Dict2.values(), Dict1.values()))
```

Comment: Probably not, since the order of items in a dict is undefined and hence it's not guaranteed that items will match.

Comment: but its helps... at least in this simple example. do you think there would be problems ?

Comment: @LauraKuttner yes there would. For example you could end up with `'duduu':'blabla'`

Comment: This would work if `Dict1` and `Dict2` were `OrderedDict()`

Comment: true story. just tied... any other ideas ?

Comment: @deceze answer is what you're looking for

Comment: @deceze you are right, I totally overlooked that fact. Your answer is the way to go!